# How important is trying to keep IE8 compatibility in 2012?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility

So recently Microsoft threw the joke that was IE6 into the recycling bin, and said that users should automatically be upgraded to the latest version of IE, if they hadn't already. Unfortunately for web designers, this means that some people (running XP) will be stuck with IE8. 
I recently started redesigning a clients website to bring it up to date, and in order to make loading times quicker, save on disk usage, and on bandwidth, I have implemented the use of CSS3 code and then a big but... IE8 Doesn't support CSS3... :( 
Is there a significant amount of users on XP / Vista / 7 who still use IE8, or have they moved to alternative, more up to date browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc?
Should I worry about trying to find a way to keep the website looking correct in all browsers? or is there a way for me to encourage visitors using IE8, to swap it for another browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this depends on how the website is used.  Is it an intranet website, a public website, or an web application that the owner dictates the version. IMO the best way to figure this out is to have Google Analytics plugged into the web app.

I can tell you that the project I am currently on doesnt have the luxuary to rule out IE8.  70% of our users that use the web app I work on use IE8.  It seems to still be the most used browser in the business world.  (at least from my experience)  Heck we still need to support IE7.

However if you can guarantee the web users are using an up to date browser, then thats a different story.  Or of course you can say, this app doesnt support IE 8 or lower.

Thats my 2 cents.

Comment: This is a public website. it shouldn't be something too big to cry about for now, as I am only using css3 for rounded divs and possibly linear gradients at some point in the future. i.e. the website will still work, but not look it's best in IE8 and under.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is the default browser in Windows 7, so expect it to hang around forever, just as IE6 has because it was the default in Windows XP.

Use http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ or http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ to ease the pain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but according to WC3 the percentage of usage is now only ~8% for IE8.

Thats still a pretty big number to turn your back on however.